# Loop through an array of div's to determine if every element has a child

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

I am looping through an array of div's and I need to check to see if **every** element of the array has a child element.

Running the code below will console.log for each element, however I only want to console.log "a child exists!" on the condition that **every tile in tilesArray** has a child element. How can this be achieved?

```
    function hasTile(tilesArray){
       for(var i = 0; i < tilesArray.length; i++){
           console.log(tilesArray[t]);
           if(tilesArray[i].firstChild){
               console.log("A child exists!");
           }else{
               console.log("No child.");
           }
       }
    }
```

index.html

```
        <div class="container" id="tileContainer">
  <!-- id listed by row-column notation. -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r1c1" onclick="main(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r1c2" onclick="main(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r1c3" onclick="main(this)"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r2c1" onclick="main(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r2c2" onclick="main(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r2c3" onclick="main(this)"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r3c1" onclick="main(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r3c2" onclick="main(this)"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 tile" id="r3c3" onclick="main(this)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End of tile container -->

<div class="container" id="turnDisplayContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6 content" id="userTurnDisplay">
      <h4>Your Turn</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-6 content" id="computerTurnDisplay">
      <h5>Computer's Turn</h5>
      <iframe src="assets/media/loading-wheel.gif" width="50" height="50" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- <div class="container" id="timerDisplayContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-18 col-md-12 content" id="timerDisplay">
      <h5>Timer</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> -->
<div class="container btnContainer">
  <div class="row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>

<img class="img img-responsive gameIcon" src="assets/img/green-ring.png" alt="Green Ring Icon" id="userIcon" />
<img class="img img-responsive gameIcon" src="assets/img/red-x.png" alt="Red X Icon" id="computerIcon" />
```

Comment: add your HTML code

Comment: You could just look for one that fails the test - if none, then all have a child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store an additional info in a local variable. Example:

```
function hasTile(tilesArray){
   var bAllHaveChild = tilesArray.length > 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < tilesArray.length; i++){
       console.log(tilesArray[t]);
       if(!tilesArray[i].firstChild){
          bAllHaveChild=false;
       }
   }
   if(bAllHaveChild)
       console.log("A child exists!");
   else
       console.log("No child.");
}
```

I hope it helps. Bye

Comment: I'm glad to help you, please don't forget to accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

I came up with a much more performant way of doing this. This particular problem is well suited for XPath via `document.evaluate`. With XPath you have the ability to create a selection path on elements that have content.

While I believe these should beat out the other options here in a foot race, the XPath typically comes in 5 times faster than the querySelectorAll filtering version.

```js
const xpath = 'boolean(.//div/div/text())'
const hasTileXPath = (id) => document.evaluate(xpath, document.getElementById(id)).booleanValue

const hasTile = (id) => Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} > div > div`)
).filter((x) => x.innerHTML).length > 0

const iterations = 1000
const iterable = Array(iterations).fill().map((x, i) => i)

const pre = performance.now()
for(let i of iterable) {
  hasTileXPath('hasNoTiles')
  hasTileXPath('hasTiles')
}
const mid = performance.now()
for(let i of iterable) {
  hasTile('hasNoTiles')
  hasTile('hasTiles')
}
const last = performance.now()

console.info(`XPath: ${iterations} iterations @ ${(mid - pre) / 1000}s`)
console.info(`SHOULD NOT HAVE TILES (XPATH) => ${hasTile('hasNoTiles')}`)
console.info(`SHOULD HAVE TILES (XPATH) => ${hasTile('hasTiles')}`)

console.info(`querySelectorAll: ${iterations} iterations @ ${(last - mid) / 1000}s`)
console.info(`SHOULD NOT HAVE TILES => ${hasTileXPath('hasNoTiles')}`)
console.info(`SHOULD HAVE TILES => ${hasTileXPath('hasTiles')}`)
```

```html
    <div id="hasNoTiles">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="hasTiles">
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>TILE</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>TILE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is really cool! Never would have thought of it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A compact way of doing it would be to check the `length` of the [`.tile:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) collection by using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). If it is 0 then all the `div`s have child elements; if not then you can loop through the array and `console.log` them all.

```
((tiles,len,x)=>{
    if(!len=(tiles=document.querySelectorAll(".tile:empty")).length)
        console.log("All .tile elements contain child elements.");
    else
        for(x=0;x<len;x++)
            console.log("div#"+tiles[x].id+" does not contain any child elements.");
})();
```

(*Apologies for the lack of a working example or for any potential typos; I wrote this up on my phone - I'll clean it up when I get back to a computer*)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tilesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(tilesArray);

var fails = tilesArray.some(function(element) {
    return element.children.length === 0;
})

if (fails) {
    console.log("No child.");       
} else {
    console.log("A child exists!");
}
```

Comment: I think this will fail if the first element has no children but the last one does.

Comment: @Dogbert, yeah, changed it

Answer (score 0):

You could return out of the function whenever a div without a child is found. That way the `console.log` won't fire unless all divs has children.

```
function hasTile(tilesArray){
   tilesArray.forEach(function(element) {
       if (element.children.length < 1) {
           return;
       }
   });
   console.log("a child exists!");
}
```